# Making a peanut shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes

I want to create this shape with Adobe-Photoshop :

[image: peanut shape]

But could't find the correct edge for making path , the result is like this with sharp edges :

[image: peanut shape with sharp edges]

I've searched for **Peanut Shaped** keyword but couldn't find any good result.
so are there any free shape-collection contains this shape ?

Comment: You can use adobe illustrator for creating shapes. It will be easy.

Comment: You tagged 'vector', however, please note that photoshop shapes are *not* vector. Yes, they are scalable to an extent but they are not vector. For vector shapes you will need to use a program like Illustrator.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 if you use the shape tool (not brushes) the shapes will be built with anchor points and paths, so pretty much vector.

Comment: [Are shapes in Photoshop vectors?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64669/are-shapes-in-photoshop-vectors)

Comment: @Luciano Pretty much, yet not completely ;)

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 My bad on the wording. The shapes are vector, they scale up and down without loss and if you copy it to Illustrator, for example, you retain all its vector properties. That makes it _completely_ vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For video tutorial: [60 Second Series: Rounding with Levels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=px_NqMfWNb8)

1. Draw a circle
2. Convert to Smart Object for filter
3. Gaussian Blur
4. Duplicate the circle
5. Move it over

[image]

6. Apply a Levels Adjustment to smooth the blur out. I'm told this is called "Level Set" in the 3D world.

[image]

And this works with any shape you want. It does work a bit better in After Effects and even Affinity Photo due to being able to apply Levels adjustment's non-destructively to the Alpha Channel but for quick brainstorming and making the shape its certainly useful in Photoshop. You'd probably then want to vectorize it but even that depends on your goal.

[image]